# Bad Request : 400 while trying to access token from Azure with SAML assertion

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, adfs4.0

I have configured Azure AD as relying party with ADFS . I am able to get SAMl assertion from ADFS after hitting to ADFS endpoint . But when am trying to get access token using same SAML assertion , it is giving bad request. I couldn't find any official documentation for such API request , there is just SAMl assertion document which doesn't clearly mentions or describes required parameters to be in request. 
Following request format am using , 
Endpoint : https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token
Header : Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body : 
grant_type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml1-bearer
scope : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_id : XXXXXXXX
client_secret  : XXXXXX
assertion : Base64 encoded complet SAML assertion received from ADFS including

I am not getting what am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the grant_type is not correct.

It should be `grant_type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml1_1-bearer`.

Please have a retry with it.

Comment: Thanks Allen !! Adding this gran type solved bad request error , but now getting "signature validation failure"

Comment: @JagdeepDhamande Carefully check if your steps to get SAML Assertion are correct. You can refer to the sample in the official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion#get-the-saml-assertion-from-adfs. (Scroll to the bottom of the page, click on "3 Closed" in the Feedback and take a closer look at the third question "SAML Assertion Grant type is hard to read") If it doesn't help, it's recommended to open a new post. That will allow more people to see this issue.